Disabled input not submitting in Angular15 even when using getRawValue()
I have a form that contains an internal form as follows:
 this.formGroup = this.fb.group({ generalRequest: new UntypedFormControl(), });
In the internal form - generalRequest, there is a field that is locked under a certain condition using disable().
When sending the form the locked field is not sent, even though I use getRawValue().
It seems that he has a problem with the fact that it is a form within a form, because in a normal form I see that this problem does not occur....

I changed the inner form type definition to UntypedFormGroup.
And now, as I wanted - on submit, the parent form  manages to receive the locked fields from the child form, by using getRawValue().
But - there is a new problem, the form throws such errors in the console, in every time there is a change or update in the field values ​​in the form:
ERROR RuntimeError: NG01000: There are no form controls registered with this group yet. If you're using ngModel, you may want to check next tick (e.g. use setTimeout).
